# Make windows 10 ask me what to do when I connect my phone

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, connection

How can i make windows ask me what to do with my phone when i connect it, again? i have chosen the option of opening it in a new window last time thinking that that will only be done for that one time.

Comment: Control Panel>AutoPlay>Devices, do this with the phone plugged in.

Comment: thank you. @Moab